# Connecting both WAN and LAN ports to the same hub

Tags: home-networking

For some reason I wish to connect the WAN port and the LAN port on a router to the same hub and make the hub is connected to both networks, the Internet and a private network. Below is a diagram of the network configuration I'd like to build.

[image: A hub is connected to the Internet, two PCs, and a router with NAT. The WAN port of the router is connected to the hub and has an IP address of 1.2.3.4. The LAN port of the router is connected to the same hub and has an IP address of 192.168.0.1. PC 1 has an IP address of 1.2.3.5. PC 2 has an IP address of 192.168.0.2, and its gateway address is 192.168.0.1.]

I tried this and it didn't work as expected. PC 1 has no problem, but PC 2 cannot connect to the Internet. When I ping 192.168.0.1 from PC 2, all packets are lost. It works well when PC 2 is connected directly to the router.

What's the problem with the network configuration above?

Comment: Run `arp -a` on PC 2 and see if the MAC corresponding to 192.168.0.1 is your router's MAC. There could be another 192.168.0.1 on the internet side.

Comment: I did and there was an incorrect MAC address, so I manually changed that to my router's MAC. Still diconnected.